# How to get only the first result from getElementsByTagName?

Tags: php, getelementsbytagname

Hi there i am using the code to get the adress of all images from url adress.
I want to ask how i can get only the first result not all matches?

Here is the code that i am using:

```
<?php


$url="http://grabo.bg/relaks-v-pamporovo-0gk5b";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}

?>
```

So please tell me how i can get only one result - the first!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`$xpath->evaluate('string(//img[1]/@src)')`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464092/xpath-get-single-value-returned-instead-of-array-php/7464905#7464905)

Comment: @Gordon How is XML evaluation the same as accessing the first HTML element?  Think you're confused on what the OP asked.

Comment: @defaultNINJA the OP wants to get only the first result, so apparently he is after the first img src value and that's what the XPath does. It's just a different way to the same result as doing `$doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');` Note that the dupe is an exact dupe of this one and not the one linked in my comment.

Comment: @Gordon Gotcha, see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`$tags` is a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object created by the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)'s [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method.  So you can access the first element returned with [`DOMNodelist::item ( int $index )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php).

For your code do: `$tags->item(0);`

Comment: I don't get it where i must put this `$tags->item(0);` and what i have to remove?

Comment: @TonnyStruck where ever it is you need to access the first element in your code. `$tags->item(0);` is the first element.  So you could do `$firstElem = $tags->item(0);` and just access that variable when you need too.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful some browsers chose to return [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) instead, which is OK, since it is a superset of [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/NodeList).
See [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: OP is not in a browser. DOM is a language agnostic interface.

Comment: I have made it. Can you please tell me how i make it start indexing from the thrird result to the end ?

Comment: Try this `echo $tags->item(0)->getAttribute('src');` . It's work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

To get the first element in the array.

Comment: `$tags` is not an array, but a `DOMNodeList` and it doesn't implement `ArrayAccess`

Comment: It's not working `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/superweb/public_html/maxoferti/test.php on line 12`